# Wordpress on bluemix cloudfoundry crashing

Tags: wordpress, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I followed the steps on the blog to get wordpress going
https://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-cloud-foundry/products/getting-started-with-wordpress-on-cloud-foundry

when I do a cf push it keeps crashing with the following lines in the error

```
2016-05-14T15:41:44.22-0700 [App/0]      OUT total size is 2,574,495  speedup is 0.99
2016-05-14T15:41:44.24-0700 [App/0]      ERR fusermount: entry for /home/vcap/app/htdocs/wp-content not found in /etc/mtab
2016-05-14T15:41:44.46-0700 [App/0]      OUT 22:41:44 sshfs   | fuse: mountpoint is not empty
2016-05-14T15:41:44.46-0700 [App/0]      OUT 22:41:44 sshfs   | fuse: if you are sure this is safe, use the 'nonempty' mount option
2016-05-14T15:41:44.64-0700 [DEA/86]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-05-14T15:41:44.68-0700 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid cf2ea899-3599-429d-a39d-97d0e99280e4 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"cf2ea899-3599-429d-a39d-97d0e99280e4", "version"=>"c94b7baf-4da4-44b5-9565-dc6945d4b3ce", "instance"=>"c4f512149613477baeb2988b50f472f2", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1463265704}
2016-05-14T15:41:44.68-0700 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid cf2ea899-3599-429d-a39d-97d0e99280e4 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"cf2ea899-3599-429d-a39d-97d0e99280e4", "version"=>"c94b7baf-4da4-44b5-9565-dc6945d4b3ce", "instance"=>"c4f512149613477baeb2988b50f472f2", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1463265704}
^[[A
```

my manifest file:

```
cf-ex-wordpress$ cat manifest.yml 
---
applications:
- name: myapp
  memory: 128M 
  path: .
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack
  host: near
  services:
  - mysql-db
  env:
    SSH_HOST: user@abc.com
    SSH_PATH: /home/user
    SSH_KEY_NAME: sshfs_rsa
    SSH_OPTS: '["cache=yes", "kernel_cache", "compression=no", "large_read"]'
vagrant@vagrant:~/Documents/shared/cf-ex-wordpress$
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your SSH mount, more details at https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/cf-ex-wordpress/issues